# Elasticsearch: Count how often a term is in each document

Tags: elasticsearch

For an entry, I can easily find out how often a specific term is used using the termvector api.

Now I want to know how often a term is in each document of my index.

```
term    | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4  [...]
'hello' |  2  |  4  |  0  |  12  [...]
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to get this statistic besides searching for my term and calling the termvector for every result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scripting to achieve this.
Follow the documentation [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_statistics_2) and [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting).
Also have a good idea on [scripted field](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) too , it helps you get additional field per document.

Sample query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "provider": "qbox"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": "_index['provider']['qbox'].tf()"
    }
  }
}
```

Where provider is the field and qbox is the value.

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: tried using this in elasticsearch v6.3, but `_index` has been deprecated, is there any way by using painless script or some other option to achieve this ?